# Check from command line if Docker has privacy access to Removable Volumes

Tags: command-line, permission, privacy

I have created a shell script that starts a Docker container running some program. If the script is run on MacOS, it creates a bind mount for `/Volumes` so that USB drives are accessible within the container.

The container won't be able to read anything from a USB drive unless Docker Desktop has been granted the "Removable Volumes" permission in System Preferences → Security & Privacy → Privacy → Files and Folders → Docker.

Is there a way to check in the script if this permission has been granted?

I want to save the user from frustrations by providing fast and informative feedback in the script if the permission is missing. The user may have denied the permission in the past and forgotten about it.